# GWT password prompt like Window.prompt

Tags: gwt, passwords, prompt

in my application I need to prompt the user to enter their password. I would like this to work the same as GWT's Window.prompt() method, except with the text in the text box masked. How would I make a dialog that does that with GWT?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this example in the GWT Showcase: [Dialog Box](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDialogBox)

You just need to change the "dialogContents" adding your custom fields, including the password field, using [PasswordTextBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PasswordTextBox.html).

Comment: Right, but is there an easier way to get the password value after the user hits the Ok button other than attaching a ClickHandler? Window.prompt() simply returns the entered value, which is what I would like to do.

Comment: Yes, you can use [Editors ►](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html). Use a SimpleBeanEditorDriver to load all the data from the form to your bean. You'll save a lot of code!